# How to solve The multi-part identifier "r.StandardRate" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error for the query shown below:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
>   The multi-part identifier "r.ResourceId" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "r.StandardRate" could not be bound.

Can you please help me figure this out?

Query:

```
select               
    vnd.Name as VendorName, 
    cct.Name as CostCentreName, 
    ct.Name as CostType,
    case when cct.IsActive = 1 then 'ACTIVE' else 'CLOSED' end as CCStatus, 
    isnull(cct.T1Code,'') as T1Code,
    cct.T2Code,  
    '' as [Month], 
    convert(varchar, year(pf.period)) + '-' + convert(varchar, month(pf.period)) as Period,
    pp.ParentProformaNo,
    pf.ProformaNo,  
    vac.TrafiguraAccountCode,
    vac.PumaAccountCode,
    pli.FinalAmt as Ammount, 
    ts.Quantity as Quantity,
    r.StandardRate as StandardRate,
    cmp.[Text] as ProformaStatus,
    '' as BillableUOM, 
    '' as Currency,
    bet.Entity as CCBilledEntity,
    bcet.Name as CCBilledCompany,
    pbet.Entity as ProformaBilledEntity, 
    pbcet.Name as ProformaBilledCompany
from 
    ProformaParent pp
join 
    Proforma pf on pf.ProformaParentId = pp.Id
join 
    ProformaCostCentre pcc on pcc.ProformaId = pf.ProformaId
join 
    CostCentre cct on cct.Id = pcc.CostCentreId
join 
    ProformaLineItems pli on pli.ProformaId = pcc.ProformaId 
                          and pli.ProformaCostCentreId = pcc.ProformaCostCentreId
join 
    Vendor vnd on vnd.Id = pf.VendorId
join 
    CostType ct on ct.Id = pli.CostTypeId
join 
    VendorAccountCode vac on vac.VendorMId = vnd.Id 
                          and vac.CostTypeMId = ct.Id
join 
    CodeMaster cmp on cmp.Id = pf.StatusId
join 
    BilledEntity bet on bet.Id = cct.BilledEntityMId
join 
    Entity bcet on bcet.Id = cct.BilledCompanyEntityId
join 
    BilledEntity pbet on pbet.Id = pf.BilledEntityId
join 
    Entity pbcet on pbcet.Id = pf.BilledCompanyId
join 
    TimeSheet ts on ts.ResourceId = r.ResourceId
```

Comment: Your query look like SQL Server.  In general, when asking a question, you should tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You  haven't joined any table aliased as `r`. Maybe you forgot to join in the needed table, or used the wrong alias?

Answer (score 3):

There is simply no object in your query named `r`.